# Is it ok to handle text file by Streamreader & StreamWriter without prior use of FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

Is it still good practise to handle the text file withot using FileStream like in an example below:

```
            StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            sw2.WriteLine("Some text");
            sw2.Close();
            StreamReader sr2= new StreamReader(filePath);
            string text =sr2.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            sr2.Close();
```

Or it is much better to use FileStream class first:

```
            string filePath= @"C:\Users\Dom\OneDrive\CODE\Temp29-01-2021\TextFile1.txt";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Create);
            StreamWriter sw= new StreamWriter(fs);
            foreach (var item in list)
            sw.WriteLine("Some text");
            sw.Close();
            fs =new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            string line;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            while ((line=sr.ReadLine()) != null)  
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            sr.Close();
```

Is it better to use it with FileStream, if so why?
Is it better to use with FileStram for asynchronous operations?
And the last question is : if we use FileStream class for writing and reading from hte same  file,
do we have to always create two seperate instances of FileStream - one for writing and another for reading from specified text file?

Comment: `new StreamWriter(filePath)` is just a convenience which opens a `FileStream` internally: it's equivalent to opening the `FileStream` yourself but with less typing

Comment: "*Is it better to use with FileStram for asynchronous operations?*" -- if you want to do asynchronous operations on the file you'll need to open the `FileStream` yourself, **and** you'll need to pass `useAsync: true` to [a constructor which supports it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_System_Int32_System_Boolean_)

Comment: "*do we have to always create two seperate instances of FileStream - one for writing and another for reading from specified text file?*" -- no, you can use the same FileStream for both reading and writing. Things won't work if you then wrap that FileStream in a StreamReader/StreamWriter however, as that does its own internal buffering

Comment: Thanks for above. But could you give some better clue regarding the last issue- how to use the same instance of FileStream for writing and reading?

Comment: Ok Think I figured it out , if we use  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
           then we can use just one instance of FileStream for both writing and reading. The only thing is that we cannot close StreamWriter  becouse then we close  also close  a stream and reading form that file will be impossible. So then I can use just streamwriter.Flush() to increase efficiency of the resources and close both StreamWriter and Streamreader afterwards.

Comment: You can open the StreamWriter with [`leaveOpen: true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) to stop it disposing the FileStream when it's disposed

Comment: Nope , leaveOpen:true  does not work i.e.  if I use either streamwriter.Flush(); or streamwriter.Dispose(); after writing to the file then when using StreamReader with the same instance of file stream ( FileStream(filePath,FileMode.OpenOrClose,FileAccess.ReadWrite);  it will read nothing form the file. Weird.

Comment: Yes, I already warned you of that. "*Things won't work if you then wrap that FileStream in a StreamReader/StreamWriter however, as that does its own internal buffering*". StreamReader has an internal buffer which it reads a block of data into, and then reads characters out of. It won't notice any changes to the FileStream if it's still reading from its buffer. If you change the position of the FileStream under it, it will also get confused.

Comment: Using a single FileStream is fine, but opening both a StreamReader and StreamWriter is unlikely to work (unless you're *very* careful and know *exactly* what you're doing)

Comment: Consluding I would say that for my intended use  it is more safe to use separate instances of FileStream for each read/write operation.